# My Adapter is getting null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager in an activity. I'm loading it like this

```
ArrayList<Fragment> arrayListFragment = new ArrayList<>();
Fragment first = Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, MainActivityFragment.class.getName());
Fragment second = Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, SecondFragment.class.getName());
arrayListFragment.add(first);
arrayListFragment.add(second);
Log.d(TAG, "Pager created " + second);
mPagerAdapter = new SwipeScreenPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    arrayListFragment, pageTitles); //This is custom adapter
```

And In onCreateView() of SecondFragment I've this log:

```
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, null, mList);
Log.d(TAG, "Initialised adapter " + this);
```

Everything works fine when I run the app. The interesting thing happen when I put app in background and then resume it after some time. The activity is restarted and viewpager is initialised again and for some reason `Log.d(TAG, "Pager created " + second);` and `Log.d(TAG, "Initialised adapter " + this);` statements print fragment with different ids. They both print same id on the first run but differ when i resume. And mAdapter becomes null when used in a fragment function (because this function is called on fragment received from viewpager).

Log statements are :

```
Pager created SecondFragment{269ef202}
Initialised adapter SecondFragment{298444fe #2 id=0x7f0e0084 android:switcher:2131624068:1}
```

From where this new fragment is being created? At first I thought it is somehow restoring the old fragment but I tried passing null in onActivityCreate like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(null);
}
```

but it is still creating separate fragment instance and also it has different id.

Comment: Is there a reason to use fragments over views?

Comment: Yeah. It's necessary. Actually, I've other ways to achieve what I want to do but I want to understand why it is happening.

Comment: Adapters are dynamic, they render and recycle as needed. When you push to the background the adapter starts dumping content cause it sees it as unneeded and will re-render it when you come to the foreground.

Comment: I put a check if(mPagerAdapter == null) before initialising adapter and when I resume app this code is executed which means mPagerAdapter was null when I resumed app. So it can't re-render unless i reinitialise it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. When the app was resumed, activity was restoring the fragment that was last associated with it in the call

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

so passing null to `super.onCreate(null)` caused it to avoid restoring last fragment. In my case I needed to create new copy of fragment because my data need to be refetched on every time activity was created so `set it null with caution`.